# Removing words from a string when the first letter of a word is capital

Tags: java

I would like to remove words with capitals from a string with capitals but I cannot figure out how to do it?

```
Original String: "bob Likes Cats"
New String: "bob"
```

Comment: what have you tried and what is your problem?

Comment: probably many ways to do this...  you could split the original string  into array of words and then reconstruct the string by omitting words that contain capitals ...

Comment: By the way your question is being down-voted because you didn't show any effort ... http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
String original = "bob Likes Cats";
String[] words = original.split(" ");

//String of the final word.
String finalword = "";

for(String word : words){
    if(Character.isUpperCase(word.charAt(0)){
        //Word has a capital letter
    }else {
        //Add the word.
        finalword += word + " ";
    }
}
```

`finalword` is now a `String` with lower case letters.

**Note that `finalword` may contain an extra space at the end.** 
To remove the space at the end:

```
finalword = finalword.substring(0,finalword.length()-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as the words in your sentences/strings seem to be separated by spaces, your algorithm might be something like:

1. Split the string on spaces into words.
2. Go over each word, and save the ones that do not have an uppercase character in it.
3. Create a new string, glueing all the saved words together, separated by a space.

You haven't specified the programming language you're using, so I will provide one in PHP as an example.

```
<?php

// Your input string.
$input = 'bob Likes Cats';

/*
    1. preg_split() the input on one or more consecutive whitespace characters.
    2. array_filter() walks over every element returned by preg_split. The callback determines whether to filter the element or not.
    3. array_filter()'s callback tests every word for an uppercase ([A-Z]) character.
*/
$filtered = array_filter(
    preg_split('/[\s]+/', $input),
    function ($word)
    {
        // preg_match() returns 1 if a match was made.
        return (preg_match('/[A-Z]/', $word) !== 1);
    }
);

// Glue back together the unfiltered words.
$output = implode(' ', $filtered);

// Outputs: bob
echo $output;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static String removeCapitalFirstLetterWords(String str) {
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();

    for (String word : str.split("\\W+")) {
        if (Character.isUpperCase(word.charAt(0)))
            continue;
        if (buf.length() > 0)
            buf.append(' ');
        buf.append(word);
    }

    return buf.toString();
}
```